# Run GitLab Runner on Docker Desktop (for testing)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to run a GitLab Runner on Docker Desktop (I run a GitLab instance and a runner locally for testing purposes).

Unfornately, I could not find out how to map the Docker socket. The manual says one should use:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

but apparently, this does not work on Windows. The information I found on StackOverflow seems to use older versions of Docker Desktop which use a Virtual Machine instead of WSL 2.

Can anybody tell me how to do the mapping on a "modern" Docker Desktop using WSL 2?

Comment: You can change settings in Docker Desktop to use the hyper-v backend instead of WSL2, which should allow this to work. Found [this resource](https://tomgregory.com/running-docker-in-docker-on-windows/) which may help you.

Comment: @sytech Thanks. So the WSL 2 backend does not support this?

Comment: I'm not sure. It should be possible to configure the runner to use the host WSL2 engine, but it would probably be by a different mechanism entirely (like the same way you might use a remote docker daemon). I know it's possible to mount the socket to windows containers (`-v //./pipe/docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine docker`) to run a docker client in a container. My guess is this won't work as-is with Linux containers. Maybe try `-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` (double leading `//`)